# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function) in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am getting the following error, which appears to be Javascript not interpreting the $ symbol.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function main.js:1
(anonymous function) main.js:1

Appended below is the main.js code. This was working fine sometime back. I am trying to find out pointers to where to look for the issues, i.e. theme, jquery imports, etc. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
$(function(){ 
var cardHeight = 0;

function _setCardHeight(){

    $(".subpage-box").each( function(){ var current_height = 
    $(this).height();

        cardHeight = ( current_height > cardHeight) ? current_height : 
        cardHeight;

    }); $(".subpage-box").each( function(){ if( $(this).height() < 
    cardHeight ){ $(this).height( cardHeight );   } });


}

function _setNavStyle(){
    $("menu-main-menu > li > a").each( function(){
        var text = $(this).html();

        if( $(this).contains("for") ){

        }
    });
}

_setNavStyle();
_setCardHeight();

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wordpress is running in noConflict mode by default, change the DOM ready wrapping to

```
jQuery(function($){ 

    // your code goes here

});
```

otherwise $ will be undefined

[***Da Codex***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since the same functionality was working about 2 weeks ago, I can only ponder if the update for Wrodpress (3.9.1) may have led to this being broken now. Also is there a mechanism (e.g. to update the theme) to get this working as it was previously (i.e. without any changes to the code).

Comment: Sup, playaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?