# Adapting jquery function to work with current wp jquery version

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cloudflare

I use cloudflare to cache my wordpress site.

However, I need to have logged in users bypass the cloudflare cache so they get the most up to date content.

To do this, I set a cookie for logged in users, and if that cookie exists, I append ?bypass=1 to each url on the page. Then I have cloudflare set to bypass any url with that parameter.

I've been adding bypass=1 to the urls on the page like this:

```
<script>
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("cachen") > -1) {
        $(function() {
            $("a").prop("href", function() {
                var url = $(this).prop("href");
                if (url.indexOf('#') == -1) {
                    if (url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
                        return url + "?bypass=1";
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

But after a recent WordPress update, that stopped working.

I find that I can precede the function with this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

and the code works.... but then I start running into some issues with some of my plugins.

My current wordpress uses jquery.js?ver=1.12.3

I'm thinking the problem is that something in the function is not compatable with the updated jquery version, but  I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jQuery.noConflict();

Here's snippet of code that worked for me:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var noConflict3 = jQuery.noConflict(); // Assign and use noConflict mode
    noConflict3(document).ready(function() {
        // My code here
    });
    $ = jQuery.noConflict(); // Had to assign it back, otherwise WP was full of JS errors
</script>
```

And here is jQuery noConflict doc: [Link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

It worked for me, I hope it works for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, found the solution.

I found in developer tools in Chrome I was getting the message:

> ?bypass=1:1202 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous
>   function) @ ?bypass=1:1202

I looked that up and found:

[Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function) in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763256/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-anonymous-function-in-wordpres)

which says:

> Wordpress is running in noConflict mode by default, change the DOM
>   ready wrapping to
>
> ```
> jQuery(function($){ 
>
>     // your code goes here
>
> });
> ```
>
> otherwise $ will be undefined

That did the trick and I am now able to remove the older version of jquery and the code works.